# How do I set a taskbar icon for Win32 application?

Tags: c++, windows, win32gui

I am creating a simple Win32 GUI application for windows 10. I want to set an icon that will appear in the taskbar when it is open. I have already defined an icon in my resource file, but it only appears next to the exe file in file explorer. when I open the app it still just shows the default icon. I'm a huge noob when it comes to windows programming, so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Any help is appreciated.

My resources.rc file:

```
#include "winuser.h"
CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "TDAssist.exe.manifest"
id ICON "icon.ico"
```

Comment: Google "reset shell icon cache" to get ahead.

Comment: What sizes/resolution icons are included in your icon.ico file?  There should be at least a 32x32 32-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The taskbar uses the icon from the window, not the first icon in the resources.

Use `LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(0),..., LR_SHARED)` to get a `HICON` and assign it to the window when you register the window class or by sending `WM_SETICON`.

The taskbar and Alt+Tab dialogs might display the .exe icon in some versions but it depends on the window style and other undocumented specifics.

Comment: I just noticed that when a start menu or desktop shortcut defines a different icon, then the taskbar uses that icon (Windows 10).

Comment: @zett42 Interesting but I'm not sure if that is always true. Application user model id or not? Already pinned to taskbar? TaskbarExceptionsIcons in the registry?